# phpMyAdmin fatal javascript error

Tags: phpmyadmin

Edit: I checked /var/log/apache2/error.log There are lots of messages like this:

> [Tue Feb 13 15:42:37.039460 2024] [core:error] [pid 1027] [client
> ::1:33658] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not
> accessible: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css
> [Tue Feb 13 15:42:55.442362 2024] [core:error] [pid 41155] [client
> ::1:41442] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not
> accessible: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/jquery/jquery-ui.css
> [Tue Feb 13 15:42:55.480593 2024] [core:error] [pid 41087] [client
> ::1:41494] AH00037: Symbolic link not allowed or link target not
> accessible: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js

There was a core update this morning.

I use Ubuntu 22.04. I have tried to open phpMyAdmin in Vivaldi and Firefox, same problem:

I can't use phpMyAdmin on my laptop. If I click any tabs in phpMyAdmin, I see "Loading", but it never loads.

just wanted to check databases. I log in to

http://localhost/phpMyAdmin/

and I see 2 messages:

> A fatal JavaScript error has occurred. Would you like to send an error
> report?

I click send error report, but just get more such messages.

I saw some older threads on stackoverflow saying PageXray extension was the cause, but I don't have that extension.

Any tips please? How can I find the culprit javascript?

I tried starting Vivaldi from the command line:

> pedro@pedro-HP:~$ vivaldi --disable-extensions

but the problem persists.

Previously I could access my database from Vivaldi, or Firefox, no problem.

Also, to check my database integrity, I opened mysql from the command line, chose a database, selected data from a table, no problem. So I would say this is not a MySQL problem.

More info:

The problem is confined to this laptop. On my little cloud server I can access my database in Vivaldi no problem!

I think the problem must be some Ubuntu update! I haven't updated the cloud server lately! Now I am not sure if I should.

More info:

The console in Developers Tools has lots of red messages, this one:

> jquery-migrate.js?v=5.1.1deb5ubuntu1:562 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot
> read properties of undefined (reading 'length') at jQuery.Tween.run
> (jquery-migrate.js?v=5.1.1deb5ubuntu1:562:36) at g
> (jquery.min.js?v=5.1.1deb5ubuntu1:2:59310) at C.fx.tick
> (jquery.min.js?v=5.1.1deb5ubuntu1:2:64313) at ft
> (jquery.min.js?v=5.1.1deb5ubuntu1:2:58702)

The last part above repeats many times!

Comment: The Apache error log says, that some files are not accesible. Are they present?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the files are present, but I think I need to change the owner and/or group to www-data. What do you think?

Post here because it's long:

> pedro@pedro-HP:~$ cd /usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/jquery/
> pedro@pedro-HP:/usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/jquery$ dir
> images    jquery-ui.css
> pedro@pedro-HP:/usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/jquery$ ls -al
> total 8 drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096  2月  4  2023 . drwxr-xr-x
> 6 www-data www-data 4096  2月  4  2023 .. lrwxrwxrwx 1 www-data
> www-data   51  1月 20  2022 images ->
> ../../../../javascript/jquery-ui/themes/base/images lrwxrwxrwx 1
> www-data www-data   58  1月 20  2022 jquery-ui.css ->
> ../../../../javascript/jquery-ui/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
> pedro@pedro-HP:/usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/jquery$ cd
> /javascript/jquery-ui/themes/base/ bash: cd:
> /javascript/jquery-ui/themes/base/: No such file or directory
> pedro@pedro-HP:/usr/share/phpmyadmin/themes/pmahomme/jquery$ cd
> /usr/share/javascript/jquery-ui/themes/base/
> pedro@pedro-HP:/usr/share/javascript/jquery-ui/themes/base$ ls -al
> total 296 drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data 12288  1月 18 17:14 .
> drwxr-xr-x 3 www-data www-data  4096  2月  3  2023 ..
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       489  1月 20  2022 accordion.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       453  9月  8  2022 accordion.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       275  1月 20  2022 all.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       272  9月  8  2022 all.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       316  1月 20  2022 autocomplete.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       299  9月  8  2022 autocomplete.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       791  1月 20  2022 base.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       770  9月  8  2022 base.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1497  1月 20  2022 button.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1137  9月  8  2022 button.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       789  1月 20  2022 checkboxradio.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       722  9月  8  2022 checkboxradio.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1526  1月 20  2022 controlgroup.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1296  9月  8  2022 controlgroup.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1581  1月 20  2022 core.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1143  9月  8  2022 core.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      3788  1月 20  2022 datepicker.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      3309  9月  8  2022 datepicker.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1753  1月 20  2022 dialog.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1518  9月  8  2022 dialog.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       253  1月 20  2022 draggable.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       242  9月  8  2022 draggable.min.css drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data  4096  1月 18 17:14 images
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     37683  9月  8  2022 jquery-ui.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     32075  9月  8  2022 jquery-ui.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1124  1月 20  2022 menu.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       911  9月  8  2022 menu.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      2952  1月 20  2022 progressbar.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      2885  9月  8  2022 progressbar.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1198  1月 20  2022 resizable.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1010  9月  8  2022 resizable.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       337  1月 20  2022 selectable.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       313  9月  8  2022 selectable.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       916  1月 20  2022 selectmenu.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       807  9月  8  2022 selectmenu.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1359  1月 20  2022 slider.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1171  9月  8  2022 slider.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       251  1月 20  2022 sortable.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       240  9月  8  2022 sortable.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       964  1月 20  2022 spinner.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       781  9月  8  2022 spinner.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root      1217  1月 20  2022 tabs.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       974  9月  8  2022 tabs.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     18138  9月  8  2022 theme.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root     14064  9月  8  2022 theme.min.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       355  1月 20  2022 tooltip.css
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root     root       331  9月  8  2022 tooltip.min.css
> pedro@pedro-HP:/usr/share/javascript/jquery-ui/themes/base$